# Writing to a text file in C (Running using ubuntu)

Tags: c, file, text

I am running the code below it manages to read the file but when I write to the second file the text file `mydetails.txt` is created but there is no text saved in it after the program has finished executing. I don't know if this is a problem with my code or with how I'm compiling / running it as I am compiling it through Ubuntu (Windows integrated version v20.04) and the code itself and text files are stored in a OneDrive. Any advice?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
        FILE * ofp;
        ofp = fopen("./mydetails.txt", "w+");
        if (ofp == NULL){
            printf("Can't open file");
            return 0;
        }else{
            fputs("This is a sentence", ofp);
            return 0;
        };
           
        fclose(ofp);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "the file"  "the second file"? I only see mydetails.txt in there. Can you clarify that? Also you have `return` in both branches of the `if` so `fclose` is never reached. Although that should not cause problems as all open files will be closed on exiting the program.

Comment: The code above will create `mydetails.txt` if it does not exist, or truncate the file if it does and then write `"This is a sentence"` to the file (you should add a `'\n'` to `fputs("This is a sentence\n", ofp);` to write a POSIX compatible file (newline after final output)). No need for an `else`, you `return 1;` on failure (change `0` to `1`). The `else` just adds unneeded indentation. Always check *close after write*, e.g. `if (fclose (ofp) == EOF) perror ("fclose(ofp)");`